# Bootstrap model fade effect, behind toggled mobile navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap navigation, very much like this one - http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/. My question is, how can I create a modal-like dark overlay in the background when the navigation is toggled and opened on mobile views. The basic idea is to bring out the navigation to focus, while fading the background underneath.

**EDIT**

Here is a bootply: http://www.bootply.com/LUDGZHNmKY

On mobile view, when the hamburger menu is opened, the area underneath should go dark/fade.

Comment: Please can you make your template a bootply.com example so we can see entire code working.  Thanks.

Comment: Try bootstrap modal without body or any content inside it!!